# jQuery - Moving background arrow in menu

Tags: jquery, image, background, slide

I would expect something like this to be pretty popular in demand but I had much trouble finding a suiting script.

I've got a basic menu build like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/btn1.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/btn2.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/btn3.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The div #menu has a background image of a small arrow. I want the arrow to move vertically in front of the corresponding menu image when you mouseover/mousemove the whole #menu div.

Also when one of the menu images has been clicked the arrow should stay in it's position in front of the corresponding menu image.

I started something but I notice it's going downwards, since it's only working when you're at the top of the page. What I have is this:

```
$('#menu').css({backgroundPosition: '5px 10px'}); //Starting position

$('#menu').mousemove(function(e){
    $('#menu').stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition: '5px ' + (e.pageY-60) + ' px'},
        {duration:100}
    )
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#menu').stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition: '5px 10px'},
        {duration:100}
    )
});
```

Please help!

ps. I'm using [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect) plugin to move background images smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some math I managed to work it out. Later on I found someone who managed to do it even faster:

```
function rPosition(elementID, mouseX, mouseY) {
  var offset = $('#'+elementID).offset();
  var x = mouseX - offset.left;
  var y = mouseY - offset.top;

  return {'x': x, 'y': y};
}
```

[Source](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-snippet-relative-mouse-position)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need js to make this possible at the active link -> style the link with css something like this:

```
a:active{backgroundPosition: 5px -50px};
```

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't read my post. I want to let it slide smoothly.

And it's position is based on where the mouse is at that moment IF the mouse is within the div. Otherwise it should move back to it's starting position.